# Store data in mysql using backbone.js and with other server scripting lanuage

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, backbone.js

I am fresher for backbone.js and go through the following.

http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/13/backbonejs-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started-part-3/

It's stored data locally. But i want to store data in mysql database.

So, any one can suggest that how can i do this?

if server scripting language required i would like to use PHP.

Thank you

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the data is saved in model using

```
model.save([attributes], [options])
```

will Save a model to your database

refer this : http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

Comment: i have collection **app.todolist** and have a data base which contain two fields **id** and **listitem**. So how can i save collection data into database?

Comment: this how it typically works
1) store the data in model/collection locally,
2) when you want to save it back to the DB write above statement(for model) , this will create a ajax request to the url specified in the collection
3)at the backend(in your case using php) you should catch the ajax request and make changes to DB